# Website with same size on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to knowa how can I let my website to its normal size on mobile (can see all the website without scroll and allow to the user to zoom up)

I tried :

- `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0, user-scalable=yes">`
- `min-width: 320 px`

but, no results

I used bootstrap and I fixed the width on 1400 px and I want to see my website on mobile like on PC ( ALL the site but with the minimum zoom )

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, erase that `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0, user-scalable=yes">`. This will zoom the whole desktop view into your small screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use class 'container-fluid' on a container div. If you want to show some html elements with the same width, you shoould use classes 'col-md-x','col-lg-x' 'col-sm-x' and 'col-xs-x'. Replace 'x' with some number from 1 to 12. If you write 12 it will be the whole width of container.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <img class="col-mg-12 col-sm-12 etc." src="example.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the official documentation on [disabling responsiveness here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)

It's fairly simple, good luck!